# Removing Duplicates With Exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, duplicates

In the image below, you will notice that there are multiple instances where DetailID is the same, however the EES_Base_Commission is 0 or 0.2.

What I'm trying to do is *filter out* of my result set cases when DetailID is the same and when EES_Base_Commission is greater than 0.

I've tried a few duplicate removal options such as the GROUP BY // HAVING, but didn't find a way to properly utilize the count in my efforts.

[Duplicate Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJyFT.png)

(The temp table is huge, so not going to link it)

```
SELECT Trade_Date, ContractNum, DetailID, EES_Base_Commission

FROM #Sales
```

---

```
SELECT Trade_Date, ContractNum, DetailID, COUNT(*) Duplicates

FROM #Sales

GROUP BY Trade_Date, ContractNum, DetailID

HAVING COUNT (*) > 1

ORDER BY DetailID
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a list of distinct DetailID's and you want to filter out any records with commission above 0.  You can do this with DISTINCT and a WHERE.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Trade_Date
, ContractNum
, DetailID
, EES_Base_Commission

FROM #Sales

WHERE EES_Base_Commission = 0
```

Comment: This resolved my issue with a minor change! I actually needed -- in this case -- to have base commission be > 0 rather than = 0. The structure though worked, thanks a lot friend!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE EES_Base_Commission > 0
AND DetailID IN
(SELECT DetailID FROM table GROUP BY DetailID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: This gives me a blank result set.

Comment: I am sorry I totally used the DISTiNCT keyword incorrectly, give me some time and I will edit my answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer, check it out and let me know